# How to restrict a scan to a specific group of keys

Tags: redis, key, redis2.8

In redis (2.8.x) I have three entity types (I define the entities).
For simplicity, let's call them *organizations*, *departments*, *users*.
When I run scan, it iterates on all keys in the memory, but brings only what matches the `match` clause.
Is there a way to restrict the `scan` to only a subset of key? For example search 
only the *users* group of keys?
Each group has a different (but consistent) key name pattern (`org:[id] dep:[id] user:[id]`)

Answer (score 2):

[SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) has an optional `MATCH` argument that accepts a glob pattern.

You can do something like this to scan through your users objects:

```
SCAN 0 MATCH user:*
```

---

**Edit as it is too long for a comment**

Clearly scan is not a magic method, a complete cycle (until you receive "0" cursor) must go through all of your keyspace. The MATCH option does the filtering in the Redis side instead of doing it in your client.

As Itamar suggested in his comment, to be able to get the keys you need without going thorough the complete keyspace, you must index them in sets (You must also maintain it on removals).

For example, if your users keys are:

```
user:31 user31data
user:45 user45data
user:67 user67data
user:13 user13data
```

You should have a `SET` of user IDs:

```
users:IDs {31, 45, 67, 13}
```

To retrieve all users data, and you probably wants both the ID and the data:

```
sort users:IDs by nosort get # get user:*
```

Comment: The scan + match first fetch all the records and then applies the filter. So it saves nothing. You can see this easily (besides reading it in the docs) by that the size of the cursor is different each call

Comment: In that case, no - you can't restrict `SCAN`. You can, however, maintain Sets that contain the key names of each entity group. Then you can SSCAN only these sets to avoid scanning the entire keyspace.